# accessing struct from c file in header

Tags: c, struct

I have 2 files for my project one called qsort.c and one called sorts.h. I have a struct declared and defined in qsort.c called record_list list, however i cant seem to access this file from my header file this is what I have in my header file:

```
void sort_empty(record_list *list) {     
    printf("%s %s %d",list -> data -> name.first,list -> data -> name.last, list -> data -> score);     
}
```

When i try to run it using  `gcc -ansi -W -Wall -pedantic` I am getting this error:

```
error: unknown type name ‘record_list’
void sort_empty(record_list *list) {
```

But I defined record_list in my c file?

Comment: I fixed it, all i needed to do was add the #include "sorts.h" after I defined my struct

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this (just based on C's compilation process). I would recommend just declaring this struct in your .h file.